How to change positioning of all child elements (and their child elements) to absolute while still keeping thier original location?
i'm working on a document editor of sort, basically
user uploads PDF => server converts to html => frontend renders html to editor => user edits => server convert the html back to pdf
issue is, when a user changes size / delete an element in the #editor div, elements below that get pushed up.
so i want to change all the element to absolute, while still keeping their postioning
function prepareDocument() {
    $("#editor").find("*").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', true);
        // Make $(this) absolute while keeping original positioning
    });

    $('#editor').find('img').on('dblclick mousedown mouseup', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).focus();
    });

    disableDragGlobally();
}

any help will be greatly appricated!! can be in either jQuery or vanila js
tried to straight up change to absolute or try to play with offset, didnt help

I don't think your approach will work, because making the elements absolutely positioned will take them out of the running layout, so they will all end up on top of each other.

yeah that whats happening when i try to make them all absolute, they all get pushed up to one spot, do you by any change got a diffrent idea?
